# Efficient way to define generating of finite groups

Tags: group-theory, definition, finitely-generated

Suppose $(G,\cdot)$ is a group and $X \subset G$ is a nonempty set. The group generated by $X$ is a subgroup of $(G,\cdot)$ with carrier set

$$\langle X \rangle = \left\{ g_1^{i_1} \cdot \ldots \cdot g_k^{i_k} \, \middle| \,  k \in \mathbb{N}, \; g_j \in X, \; i_j \in \mathbb{Z} \right\} .$$

For finite groups, this definition is unnecessarily complicated. Let's say that $|G| = n$, then

$$\langle X \rangle = \left\{ g_1^{i_1} \cdot \ldots \cdot g_k^{i_k} \, \middle| \,  k \in \mathbb{N}, \; \color{darkred}{k \leq n}, \; g_j \in X, \; i_j \in \mathbb{N}, \; \color{darkred}{i_j \leq n} \right\} .$$

Suddenly, a computer would be able to generate the set, though it would make many redundant computations of the same elements.

We can do better. Let's denote $\operatorname{ord} (g)$ the order of $g \in G$ in $(G,\cdot)$, then

$$\langle X \rangle = \left\{ g_1^{i_1} \cdot \ldots \cdot g_k^{i_k} \, \middle| \,  k \in \mathbb{N}, \; k \leq n, \; g_j \in X, \; i_j \in \mathbb{N}, \; \color{darkred}{i_j < \operatorname{ord} (g_j)} \right\} .$$

What is the most "efficient" (in the sense that it would on average generate each element the least amount of times) way of writing such definition? How far can we go?

I can't really tell if this problem is an obvious one or if it is something hard. Recommending some literature would be aslo very appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean $g_j \in X$?

Comment: @AHusain Of course, edited, thank you.

Comment: It seems like this would depend on how the elements are identified, combined, and compared for equality (whether on paper or by a computer).

Comment: @aschepler By "efficient" I don't mean "fastest for computers", I mean it in a more vague sense. The way I look at it is "how can I describe this concept as *tightly* as possible without any loss on generality", and that, I believe, doesn't depend on element identification or comparison. 
It's somewhat reminiscent of group homomorphism definition – group homomorphism can be defined as an operation that preserves group multiplication, inversion and identity, but the only operation needed is multiplication, the other two can be deduced from it.

Comment: Except your descriptions progress from short to long, introducing more ideas within each. So it's not the description itself you want to be efficient or tight - is it the number of formulae which can be used to be certain the generated subgroup is covered?

Comment: @aschepler You are right. I didn't look at my question that way, thank you. I added a little explanation about what I mean by saying "efficient".

Comment: In your initial definition of $\langle X\  \rangle$, you can take $i_j = \pm 1$ (or even $i_j = 1$ if $G$ is finite). Unless the group is abelian or perhaps nilpotent or solvable, a typical shortest expression for a group element will not have a large number of adjacent equal generators, so there is no particular advantage in takinh $i_j \in {\mathbb Z}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt That is true. I kinda just wanted to kick it off with a general definition, didn't notice it was needlessly complicated. Thank you. I will keep it this way though to better translate illustrate the following examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option:
For a finite group $(G,\cdot)$ and nonempty subset $X \subset G$,
define $Y_0 = \{1_G\}$, $Y_1 = X$, and
$$ Y_{k+1} =  \left\{ \space f \cdot g \, \middle| \, f \in X,\; g \in Y_k \right\} \setminus \bigcup_{i=0}^{k} Y_i $$

Because the group is finite, for some $n$ all sets after $Y_n$ are empty, and the result is $$\langle X \rangle = \bigcup_{i=0}^n Y_i$$

This is essentially a breadth-first search algorithm: $Y_k$ contains the new nodes found during step $k$, and $\bigcup_{i=0}^{k} Y_i$ all nodes found by that step. The next step then finds any neighbors of the new nodes that had not been found before.

The question asked for a definition that "would on average generate each element the least amount of times", so lets evaluate: The sequence of $Y_k$ is a partition of $\langle X \rangle$, so each element of $\langle X \rangle$ is multiplied exactly once with every element of $X$ and there are a total of $|X| |\langle X \rangle|$ evaluations of $ f \cdot g $. The clear minimum would be $|\langle X \rangle|$, so at least for small $X$ we're not far off.

**edit:**
This would be inefficient if X is not a minimal generating set. If that's a possibility, we can augment the above to iteratively add generators:

Pick any $g_0 \in X$, and compute $Z_0 = \langle g_0 \rangle$ as above. Then, iteratively compute each $Z_i = \langle g_0,g_1,...,g_i \rangle$ starting from $Z_{i-1}$ instead of $\{1_G\}$, and picking $g_i$ from $X \setminus Z_{i-1}$. The result is the $Z_k$ that contains all of $X$.

Comment: Try applying it to $S_n$ and $X$ consisting of all $2$-cycles.

Comment: Good point, it's not very efficient if X is redundant. The patch I can think of would to use an iterative process: Pick a generator $g_0$ from $X$, generate $Z_0 = \langle g_0 \rangle$ starting from $\{1_G\}$, pick the next generator from $X \setminus Z_0$ and use $Z_0$ as the starting set, and repeat until $X \subset Z_k$. This avoids using elements of $X$ that aren't needed.

Comment: @quaternic That is a really cool strategy, thank you! While it isn't what I was looking for (my bad in not explaining that), it's still very cool as it gives some great insight by building the subgroup step by step.

Comment: @quaternic Hey, it's me again, one day later. It might have just been that I didn't fully understand what you meant. What you described actually helped me with coming up with a satisfying answer that I wasn't able to justify before: $\langle X \rangle = \left\{ g_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot g_k \, \middle| \,  k \in \mathbb{N}, \; k \leq n, \; g_j \in X \right\}$ for $n = |G|$. The idea is that each non-empty $Y_i$ must contain at least one element, but $G$ contains at most n elements, so $Y_{n+1}$ must be empty and we don't need to create longer words. So thank you! I will accept your answer now. <3